# ¿Cómo puedo usar shuffle si tengo un array con radiobutton en PHP?

Tags: php

Buen día, tengo que realizar una encuesta y que las opciones en cada pregunta me salga en diferente orden, al momento de que yo quiero imprimir las opciones con su radio button no me sale, pero si me los imprime por separado pero sin el radio

```
              if ($op1 !== "") {                  
                  echo'<input type="radio" name="ans" value="0" required>'.$op1.'<br /><br />';
                }
              if ($op2 !== "") {
                  echo'<input type="radio" name="ans" value="0" required>'.$op2.'<br /><br />';
                }
              if ($op3 !== "") {
                  echo'<input type="radio" name="ans" value="0" required>'.$op3.'<br /><br />';
                }
              if ($respuesta !== "") {
                  echo'<input type="radio" name="ans" value="1" required>'.$respuesta.'<br /><br />';
                }
              }
              $array_respuestas=array($op1, $op2, $op3, $respuesta);
              shuffle($array_respuestas);
              echo implode(",",$array_respuestas);
```

Comment: ¿Lo que buscas es imprimir las opciones en orden aleatorio? Deberías considerar crear un arreglo de respuestas con sus propios IDs para luego poder analizar las respuestas en base al ID. ¿Te interesa una respuesta con un cambio radical a tu código?

Comment: si lo que quiero es que me las imprima en aleatoria, estoy abierta a cualquier propuesta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrías encarar el problema creando una variable para la pregunta, que contenga los siguientes datos:

- El ID de la pregunta.
- La pregunta.
- Un arreglo de opciones (*las posibles respuestas a la pregunta*) con:

  - Un `"ID"` para cada una.
  - La supuesta respuesta.
- El `ID` de la opción correcta.

**Ejemplo:**

```
<?php
$pregunta = [
    'id' => 1,
    'pregunta' => '¿Esta es una pregunta?',
    'respuesta' => 3, // ID opción correcta
    'opciones' => [
        ['texto'=> "Respuesta 1", 'id'=> 1],
        ['texto'=> "Respuesta 2", 'id'=> 2],
        ['texto'=> "Respuesta 3", 'id'=> 3], // <- correcta
        ['texto'=> "Respuesta 4", 'id'=> 4],
    ],
];
```

---

#### Opción 1: envío de datos y análisis con `PHP`

Con estos datos luego podrías:

- utilizar `shuffle` para ordenar el arreglo de opciones
- con un `foreach` imprimirlos
- al `name` podrías agregar el `ID` de la pregunta para saber los datos son para de ESA pregunta
- y en el `value` utilizar el `ID` de cada una.

**Ejemplo:**

```
<?php

//... AQUI podrias hacer el analisis de envío del formulario

//... AQUI la apertura del formulario

//Vamos a ordenar e imprimir las opciones
shuffle($pregunta['opciones']);
foreach ($pregunta['opciones'] as $opcion) {
    echo '<input type="radio" name="ans'.$pregunta['id'].'" value="'.$opcion['id'].'" required>'.$opcion['texto'].'<br /><br />';
}

//... AQUI cierre del formulario
```

Luego una vez enviado el formulario con la respuesta, solo quedaría validar que la respuesta seleccionada se la respuesta correcta.

**Ejemplo: envío por POST**

```
//... Análisis de la respuesta enviada por POST
if ($_POST['ans'.$pregunta['id']] == $pregunta['respuesta']) {
    echo "Correcto! :)";
} else {
    echo "Incorrecto! :(";
}
```

---

#### Opción 2: análisis de datos con `JavaScript` (*hackeable*)

Con estos datos luego podrías:

- utilizar `shuffle` para ordenar el arreglo de opciones
- con un `foreach` imprimirlos
- y en el `value` indicar `"1"` para la respuesta correcta.

**Ejemplo:**

```
<?php

//... código

//Vamos a ordenar e imprimir las opciones
shuffle($pregunta['opciones']);
foreach ($pregunta['opciones'] as $opcion) {
    $value = $opcion['id'] == $pregunta['respuesta'] ? '1' : '0';
    echo '<input type="radio" name="ans" value="'.$value.'" required>'.$opcion['texto'].'<br /><br />';
}
```

Comment: corrigo,como le das el valor a la respuesta?

Comment: si, 3 opciones valen 0 y una vale 1

Comment: @Pau1295, otra forma de verlo sería... cada respuesta correcta suma un punto, no?

Comment: si, de hecho en la otra parte del código, si selecciona la opc4 automáticamente me va a sumar 1 y al final me da la calificación

Comment: @Pau1295 ¿con `javascript` sumas automáticamente? Si es así, no te recomiendo imprimir el valor de cada respuesta en cada `input`... volvemos a lo que te comentaba antes, es fácilmente hackeable

Comment: @Pau1295, si no te interesa que sea hackeable... podrías simplemente volver a `value="1"` y listo. Avisame asi actualizo mi respuesta.

Comment: no importa que sea hackeable

Comment: @Pau1295, he actualizado mi respuesta con una segunda opción.